# In Bash, how to set stdout to a variable inside tee

Tags: bash, command, pipe, stdout, tee

Using Bash, I want to inspect the output on the terminal but at the same time feed that output to another command for further processing. Here I use `tee`

```
#!/bin/bash

function printToStdout() {
  echo "Hello World is printed to stdout"
  echo "This is the second line"
}
printToStdout | tee >(grep Hello)
```

**Output**:

```
Hello World is printed to stdout
This is the second line
Hello World is printed to stdout
```

So far so good. But I need the `grep` result to pass into more than 1 custom function for further processing. Hence, I try to store that to a variable by using command substitution inside `tee`:

```
printToStdout | tee >(myVar=`grep Hello`)
echo "myVar: " $myVar
```

**Expected Output**

```
Hello World is printed to stdout
This is the second line
myVar: Hello World is printed to stdout
```

**But what I got is an Unexpected Missing Output for myVar**

```
Hello World is printed to stdout
This is the second line
myVar:
```

**Question**: how can I get the output of grep into myVar so that I can further process it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```sh
#!/bin/bash

function printToStdout() {
  echo "Hello World is printed to stdout"
  echo "This is the second line"
}

{ myVar=$(printToStdout | tee >(grep Hello) >&3); } 3>&1

echo "myVar: " $myVar
```

Result:

```
Hello World is printed to stdout
This is the second line
myVar:  Hello World is printed to stdout
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY0xC8IwEIX3/IpnLKWdinRT7Oxu0bltThOISUnSQWp/eywpCMIN73jf3dd3Xsa431W9MlW/Low9JjMEZQ1Gp0xo7TUIO4WixMwAGqQFv5DWFnfrtIDyG0gCwcInmP/IVq79OkESPA3WCGhliLOFsRmv961z56z4M@GDQISmeDoakVQlmrwuT1hQN/mBse13uj6CI0sJMX4B)

Comment: This is a genius way to use var assignment and pipe together!